# How do I get windows ENV from WSL bash script?

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to export Windows Username to WSL ENV on Windows10 1709 + Ubuntu(WSL).

```
export WIN_USERNAME=$(cmd.exe /C "echo %USERNAME%")
```

Above command works on WSL shell, but it fails when I try to add it to `~/.profile`

I also tried to escape it as 
`export WIN_USERNAME=$(cmd.exe\ /C\ \"echo %USERNAME%\")`
It also fails.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: What about specifying the full path of cmd.exe as  /mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

the issue here is in bash script, cmd.exe will try to access your current path, which is a linux path that do not exist in Windows, hence it should throw a error and remain in a interactive command prompt. you can use powershell to access your username like following:

```
export WIN_USERNAME="$(powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command "\$Env:UserName")"
```